# Showing that the bounded $C \subseteq L^p[0,1]$ is uniformly integrable.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, uniform-integrability

**Exrcise :**

> Let $C \subseteq L^p[0,1], 1 < p < \infty$ be bounded. Show that $C$ is uniformly integrable.

**Attempt :**

It is $L^p[0,1] \subseteq L^1[0,1]$ and $L^p[0,1] \hookrightarrow L^1[0,1] \implies \exists c>0 : \|u\|_1 \leq c \|u\|_p \; \forall u \in L^p$. Thus $C$ is bounded in $L^1[0,1]$ as well. Now, we have :
$$\int_A |u| \mathrm{d}x = \int_{[0,1]} |u| \chi_A \mathrm{d}x \leq \|u\|_p \|\chi_A\|_{p'} \leq M\left(\int_{[0,1]} \chi_A^{p'}\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p'} = M |A|_N^{1/p}$$
For $|A|_N < \varepsilon$ (aka arbitrarilly small) we get the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of uniform integrability.

**Question :** Is my approach correct and rigorous ?

Comment: looks good ..........

Comment: @daw Thanks for the update !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do did look correct. Here are some remarks:

- We can take $c=1$ (you work with Lebesgue measure, I guess).
- What is the meaning of $\left\lvert A \right\rvert_N$? What you obtained from Hölder's inequality is 
  $$\int_A |u| \mathrm{d}x\leqslant M\left\lvert A\right\rvert^{(p-1)/p}
    $$ 
  hence it suffices, for a fixed $\varepsilon$, to find $\delta$ such that $M\delta^{(p-1)/p}\lt\varepsilon$.